# Abosultely position tabel getting cut off at the end of the page

Tags: html, css

I have created a drop down table function, which creates a table dropdown of suggestion when a user enters something in an input box. The input box is relatively positioned and the drop down table is absolutely positioned:

[image]

However, the absolutely positioned table gets cut off at the end of the document and there is no scroll bar at the right at the browser.

Is there a way for the absolutely positioned element to kind of push the page down creating a scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

You could try fixing the table headers (PartNumber, LocationName) like this:

```
th {
    position: fixed
}
```

This will hopefully create a scrollbar for the remainder of the table. Let me know if this works.